How to pass a property value from Java to karate-config.js or karate feature file in multi-threaded environment
I'm trying to set a variable in one of the Java class as system variable in Runner.path()
private void triggerAPIAutomationTestRun(TestCaseExecutionRequest request, String testsDirPath) {
        try {
            // Setting required properties into System property so that it's accessible in karate-config.js
            Results results = Runner.path("file:" + testsDirPath + SLASH + TESTCASE)
                    .outputCucumberJson(true)
                    .systemProperty("tests.run.env", request.getEnv())
                    .systemProperty("service.port", serverPort)
                    .parallel(PARALLEL_THREAD_COUNT);
            testsRunReportService.generateTestReport(request, testsDirPath, results.getReportDir());
            testsRunReportService.sendRunReportMail(request, (SLASH + TEST_REPORT_VIEWER + testsDirPath + SLASH + REPORTS + SLASH
                    + API_AUTOMATION_TEST + SLASH + CUCUMBER_HTML_REPORTS + SLASH + RUN_REPORT_FILE_NAME),
                    false, true);
            log.info("Test case run completed for service = " + request.getServiceName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to run API automation tests. Cause : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            testsRunReportService.sendRunReportMail(request, "", false, false);
        }
    }

And I'm accessing "tests.run.env" in karate-config.json and doing some conditional logic based on this variable value.
Now the problem I'm facing is that "tests.run.env" is getting overriden in multi-threaded env when multiple requests are coming concurrently.
How to solve this use?
karate-config.json file -
function fn() {

    var env = karate.properties['tests.run.env'];
    karate.log('Value of tests.run.env : ', env);

    var config = {
        hostname : 'abc.com',
        qa_user_username: 'abc@gmail.com',
        qa_user_password: 'sdsfghyj'
    };

    if (env == 'local') {
        var port = karate.properties['service.port'];
        config.hostname = '127.0.0.1:' + port
    } else if (env == 'sandbox-lower') {
        config.hostname = 'abclower.com'
    } else if (env == 'uat') {
        config.hostname = 'abcuat.com'
    } else {
        config.hostname = 'abcprod.com'
    }

//    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
//    karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);

    return config;
}

And using this hostname in feature file as shown below -


really can't say from here. karate.properties is supposed to "snapshot" the java system properties when the test starts, so I really don't know why you are facing this. I think the only way to figure this out is for you to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
